# Using MVC in Webforms for Ajax calls

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, webforms, hybrid

I have a webforms project and I would like to integrate MVC into it so that I can make ajax calls from a javascript file on the main.aspx page of the webforms project to a controller in the MVC project and have data returned back to the client side.
How can I access the functions in the MVC project from my ajax calls?

Comment: You don't need MVC to have an endpoint that returns XML or JSON for your ajax calls. You just need a service of some kind.

Comment: That seems quite pointless considering how many alternatives there are most some of which better than MVC. There are Page Methods, AJAX Enabled WCF Services and Web API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you need to add an MVC project. You could just create an http handler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170882/jQuery-AJAX-and-HttpHandlers-in-ASP-NET